# How to update models.py when I create a new table in my database?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I was wondering how to automatically update my models.py in a specific app in django. I created a new table in my database through HeidySQL, when i syncdb, i see the table appears in the directory in the command line, but not in models.py . I also tried migrate and make migrations but still not working.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing it that way? You should create a new model, then use migrations to create the corresponding database table.

Comment: Well, its much more comfortable to use an interface like HeidySQL

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you can not "straightforward" convert an SQL table to a model, since a database allows to add all kind of content, for which it is hard to construct Django models. What if for example a column has two or more foreign key constraints to multiple tables? Then that means this is some sort of `ForeignKey` to separate models concurrently, etc. One could say that a "Django model" is *richer* than an SQL table, since information "gets lost" during the migration.

Comment: But on the 1st time I synced them, it created an automatic models.py with all the tables, SK, FK and all its stuff, isn't it possible to do the same now?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i tried to type it manually in models.py, ran makemigrations and migrate, and now it is not updated in my database(i cant see the new table from models in heydisql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manage.py migrate` and `makemigrations` commands work in the opposite direction that you are describing here. If you want to generate a starter template of your models based on the current layout of the database, you can try using the `inspectdb` command.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > temp_models.py
```

This will generate a starter model for every table in the database. You should review and update the generated models so they make sense with your app. Take special note of lines ending with the comment `# This field type is a guess.`

Once you are satisfied with the new models, copy them over to the app's models.py file.

Hope that helps!